# Image download with PHP header: Images not displaying in Windows Photo Viewer and MacOS Preview

Tags: php, image, download, header, preview

I have a problem using image download with the PHP header function: The image is downloading properly, can be viewed in Photoshop, but cannot be opened in Windows Photo Viewer and MacOS Preview. Here ist the (simple) code I am using:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$url.'"');
readfile($image);
```

Thank you so much,

Alex

Comment: `filename` is what you want the file to be named on the client. it is **NOT** the url of the file. e.g. you want `filename=kittens.jpg`, not `filename=http://example.com/kittens.jpg`.

Comment: yes, you are right. the name of the variable is a little bit misleading; the filename is saved as "url" in the database, that's the reason for the caption.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (maybe interesting for others): Simply do not execute any HTML/JavaScript code, before the PHP Header code is executed. Otherwise the HTML/Javascript code is written inside the image file and therefore it cannot be displayed in Windows Photo Viewer etc. Photoshop seems to filter it out somehow.